# Validate when keystore.load() is canceled

Tags: java, applet, keystore, smartcard, smartcard-reader

I need to write an applet that reads info from smartcards, I based my script on the code example provided by [@Jovo Krneta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180838/php-javascript-java-applet-smart-card-signing-pdf-on-server/) here.

My concern is about this specific piece of code:

```
keyStore.load(null, null); // opens the windows security window
Enumeration<String> enums = keyStore.aliases(); // looks for local certificates

while (enums.hasMoreElements()) {
    this.jComboBox1.addItem((String) enums.nextElement());
}
```

I'm finding it hard to find a way to validate if the user clicked on Cancel once the window is opened.

[image]

My question is if exists something like

```
keyStore.load(null, null);
if(keyStore.canceled()){
   // do nothing
}else{
    Enumeration<String> enums = keyStore.aliases(); // looks for local certificates 
    while (enums.hasMoreElements()) {
        this.jComboBox1.addItem((String) enums.nextElement());
    }
}
```